# JSON Object not correct formatted into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, arrays, json

I want to use a JSON Object as a key -> value array in JavaScript, but i didn't get why it is not returning my Object in the way i want to:

I tried the following:

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(result);

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 

    // Using Number() to convert key to number type 
    // Using obj[key] to retrieve key value 
    return [Number(key), obj[key]]; 
}); 

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
    for(var z = 0; z < result[i].length; z++) { 
        console.log(result[i][z]); 
    } 
    
}
```

But i am getting as result the following lines in the console.log

```
writeback.js:159 0
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 1
writeback.js:159 {
writeback.js:159 2
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 3
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 4
writeback.js:159 r
writeback.js:159 5
writeback.js:159 o
writeback.js:159 6
writeback.js:159 w
writeback.js:159 7
writeback.js:159 n
writeback.js:159 8
writeback.js:159 u
writeback.js:159 9
writeback.js:159 m
writeback.js:159 10
writeback.js:159 b
writeback.js:159 11
writeback.js:159 e
writeback.js:159 12
writeback.js:159 r
writeback.js:159 13
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 14
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 15
writeback.js:159 :
writeback.js:159 16
writeback.js:159 1
writeback.js:159 17
writeback.js:159 ,
writeback.js:159 18
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 19
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 20
writeback.js:159 I
writeback.js:159 21
writeback.js:159 D
writeback.js:159 22
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 23
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 24
writeback.js:159 :
writeback.js:159 25
writeback.js:159 1
writeback.js:159 26
writeback.js:159 }
writeback.js:159 27
writeback.js:159 {
writeback.js:159 28
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 29
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 30
writeback.js:159 r
writeback.js:159 31
writeback.js:159 o
writeback.js:159 32
writeback.js:159 w
writeback.js:159 33
writeback.js:159 n
writeback.js:159 34
writeback.js:159 u
writeback.js:159 35
writeback.js:159 m
writeback.js:159 36
writeback.js:159 b
writeback.js:159 37
writeback.js:159 e
writeback.js:159 38
writeback.js:159 r
writeback.js:159 39
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 40
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 41
writeback.js:159 :
writeback.js:159 42
writeback.js:159 2
writeback.js:159 43
writeback.js:159 ,
writeback.js:159 44
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 45
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 46
writeback.js:159 I
writeback.js:159 47
writeback.js:159 D
writeback.js:159 48
writeback.js:159 \
writeback.js:159 49
writeback.js:159 "
writeback.js:159 50
writeback.js:159 :
writeback.js:159 51
writeback.js:159 2
writeback.js:159 52
writeback.js:159 }
writeback.js:159 53
writeback.js:159 "
```

It seems like every character into the JSON object is getting a key but the key and the value is in the object itself.

UPDATE: The value of the variable result is

```
{"rownumber":1,"ID":1}{"rownumber":2,"ID":2}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` creates a string, not an object.

Comment: If you already have an object, just process it directly, you don't need to convert it to JSON.

Comment: post your input object also

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I edited the original post and posted the input object as well.

Comment: Is there a way you can edit the value of result to be two correctly formatted json objects in an array, or combine the result into one json object? As it stands, you would first need to parse that string into two objects before trying to manipulate it as regular json objects.

Comment: is `result` an array ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee No, it is a string.

Comment: This will cause an exception while parsing as, this is not valid JSON string

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are passing an `Object` to `JSON.stringify` which converts the object into a `String` (see the first comment from @Barmar).

Just change the line

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(result);
```

into

```
var obj = result;
```

**=== EDIT ===**

After the OP updated the question, the above advice is in fact not enough to solve the problem.

The input is a `String` with the following content:

`'{"rownumber":1,"ID":1}{"rownumber":2,"ID":2}'`

Since it is *not a valid JSON string*, using just `JSON.parse` isn't sufficient. First, the string needs to be split into 2 separate "object descriptions" and then each of these needs to be passed to `JSON.parse`.

```
var splitted = result.
  split('}{'). // <-- split in 2
  map((partialObjectStr, i) => {
    return JSON.parse( // <-- parse into object
      i < 1 
        ? `${partialObjectStr}}` // <-- add right } before parsing
        : `{${partialObjectStr}` // <-- add left { before parsing
    );
  });

var objA = splitted[0];
var objB = splitted[1];

console.log(objA);
console.log(objB);
```

Comment: Now i am getting the same result but with less characters because it is removing all the "\" and """ signs in my obj variable. The problem is that the obj that i wanna give as parameter input into the function is as one string but i need them as two seperate objects {"rownumber":1,"ID":1}{ rownumber: 2, ID: 2 }. How can i do this?

Comment: If you need accurate answers, you need to provide all the information ;-)  My answer is based on guessing what the initial value of `result` is. That guessing in turn is based on what you've shown as output in the console. Please edit your question and I'll refine my answer.

Comment: I posted the input object and the value. Would that be enough?

Answer (score -2):

you should wrap **JSON.parse()** if you want to mutate or make copy in memory

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```

otherwise just remove **JSON.stringify()**

```
var obj = result;
```

Comment: Completely unneeded. This turns and `Object` into a `String` and then back into an `Object`. Just omit `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` and you'd have the same result.

Comment: @david stringify+parse would clone the object, while obj=result will point both to the same object.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, technically you are correct. However, in regards to the problem that has been stated, this solution does not add any valuable information that helps solving the problem.